# Could not find or load main class io.gatling.recorder.GatlingRecorder

Tags: gatling

I have set GATLING_HOME = "F:\gatling\" in environment variable but still i'm getting below issue.

Could not find or load main class io.gatling.recorder.GatlingRecorder

How to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Need to set GATLING_HOME = "F:\gatling"

On Linux/Unix:

```
$GATLING_HOME/bin/recorder.sh
```

On Windows:

```
%GATLING_HOME%\bin\recorder.bat
```